# Which type of Request should I use?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am a little bit confused: I'm developping an android app and I'm using `Volley` library to manage the requests to the API. But for some reasons, I get a 401 response from the server for some requests.
So I think I'm using the wrong type of request. What should I use if I want to send `GET/POST/DELETE/PUT` requests with `non-JSON` parameters and receive `JSON` data ?
Thx in advance

Comment: 401 means "Unauthorized", i.e., access to the server requires some kind of authentication. You'd better contact the server administrator (developer) for the kind of authentication and apply for access (a token, user & pwd, file, etc).

Comment: I know what a 401 error is. And I get it because of my request.

Comment: Maybe some non-safe request has been restricted like POST/DELETE/PUT. You should try to use GET request.

Comment: Okay thanks but let's forget about the 401 and the methods and focus on the type of request please : my question is "which one should I use" and not "which http method should I use".

Comment: @Amina its depend on the webservices you are consuming. if webservices needs only the GET params you just have to use the GET method in the Volly request. Please ask from the developer whom developed the webservices.

Comment: @Amina can you paste the Webservice code you are using

Comment: I know that, but that's not the problem. I just want to know if I should use StringRequest or JsonRequest or whatever. The http method is not the problem.

Comment: @Amina, for the updated question, JsonRequest is the best match for you.